# Number/Currency Formatting

Tags: java, regex, currency

I do have Bulgarian currency in a format like `+000000027511,00`.I want to convert this format to `27511.00`,I have tried it and got using substring combinations and regex,Is there any patterns or regex to do it in more simplified way?

Implementation I tried,

```
String currency= "+000000027511"; // "[1234]" String
String currencyFormatted=currency.substring(1);
System.out.println(currencyFormatted.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""));
```

Comment: Make a big decimal of it and use `setScale` with 2, or parse it as a float and use `NumberFormat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String s = "+000000027511,00";
String r = s.replaceFirst("^\\+?0*", "");
r = r.replace(',', '.');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Double.valueOf` + `DecimalFormat.format`, or `DecimalFormat.parse + format`, or `BigDecimal` you can do it as this.

```
  // method 1 (parsing to Float)
  String s = "+000000027511,00".replace(",", ".");
  Double f = Double.valueOf(s);
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#########0.00");
  String formatted = df.format(f);
  System.out.println(formatted);

  // method 2 (parsing using Decimal Format)
  s = "+000000027511,00";
  DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("+#########0.00;-#########0.00");
  Number n = df2.parse(s);
  df = new DecimalFormat("#########0.00");
  formatted = df.format(n);
  System.out.println(formatted);

  // method 3 (using BigDecimal)
  BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(s.replace(",", "."));
  b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  System.out.println(b.toPlainString());
```

Will print

```
27511.00
27511.00
27511.00
```

Comment: I would use `double` rather than `float` in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    String s = "+000000027511,00";
    s = s.replace("+", "").replaceAll("^0+", "").replace(',', '.');
    System.out.println(s);
```